# Find Area node is collided is celling, floor or wall in godot4

Tags: game-development, gdscript, 3d-modelling, godot4

I have a area node in godot4 which can scale up and down and also rotate. there are celling, floor and wall in scene, my area node place  between them and can scale up, when this area got bigger can collide with other areas like floor, wall or celling. I want to know that area i collided  is wall, floor or celling.
I know there is characterbody node which has method that shows node which is collided is wall, floor or ceiling. but I want to use area node for both of them. how can I find node which is collided is wall, celling or floor?
Thanks in advance.

this is my code:
func my_raycast(myray:RayCast3D,myarea:Area3D):
myray.global_position = center_pivot.global_position
myray.enabled = true

```
myray.target_position = myarea.global_position - myray.global_position
if(myray.is_colliding()):
    if(myray.get_collider().name==myarea.name):
        #myray.enabled = false
        print("colided")
        
        var mynormal = myray.get_collision_normal()
        print(myray.get_collision_normal())
        
        if(mynormal.is_zero_approx()):
        mynormal = -myray.global_position.direction_to(myray.to_global(myray.target_position))
            
        var is_floor:bool = mynormal.angle_to(myarea.transform.basis.y/myarea.scale.y) <= PI/4
        var is_ceiling:bool = mynormal.angle_to(myarea.transform.basis.y/myarea.scale.y) <= PI/4
        var is_wall:bool = mynormal.angle_to(myarea.transform.basis.y/myarea.scale.y) <= PI/4
```

===============
never condition of is_zero_approx got true.

I used raycast for finding normal of node I collided but I don't have any idea, how to find answer? I don't want to use layer or tags on wall, floor and celling @Theorat

Comment: *"I don't want to use layer or tags on wall, floor and ceiling?"*
Why is that? The simplest way is to add the collision objects to a group and check if `collider.is_in_group()`.

Comment: That situation of a zero normal shouldn't happen, but it began happening to me in a very hard to isolate situation, so I ended up patching it my code. I do not know if the underlying issue has been fixed since.

Comment: I looked it up, it was a problem with back faces, and seems to be fixed. I'll remove that bit from the answer. Edit: done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how do you decide where to aim a raycast, but we can come back to that.

---

This is how you would mimic what character body does with a raycast:

```
if raycast.is_colliding():
    var normal := raycast.get_collision_normal()
    var is_floor := normal.angle_to(up_direction) <= floor_max_angle
    var is_ceiling := (-normal).angle_to(up_direction) <= floor_max_angle
    var is_wall := not result.is_floor and not result.is_ceiling
```

You, of course, need to define `up_direction` and `floor_max_angle`, just like with the actual character body. By default `up_direction` will be the `UP` constant, and `floor_max_angle` is 45º (`PI/4`).

---

So where do you aim the raycast? Just going for the origin of the other object transform is not correct... The origin might be anywhere relative to the actual collision shape. Even aiming to the center of the collision shape might not be correct as the collision might happen off-center.

If the goal is mimic the character body, you would be checking where it collides as it moves.

So, I don't know if you want to try a shape cast that mimics the motion of your area, or something else. I'll link here [another answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207062/10408) where I talk about checking the collisions from code, which might get you started on that.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Theraot. but what do you mean up_direction. is it vector(0,1,0). when node is rotated, how about up direction?

Comment: @ehsan That is a design decision. Should what is considered floor change when the node is rotated? Should it change because something else (e.g. a mechanic of changing the direction of gravity)?

Comment: how to find wall I collide is left or right ? @Theraot

Comment: @ehsan You could use the same approach, but this time you need to define the direction to one of the sides instead of the up direction. Then you can get the angle of the normal to that side. Assuming you do not need special cases for other angles, check if it is greater or lesser than a quarter turn (`PI/2`) to tell if it the wall is on the same or the opposite side. *Edit: again you decide when that direction changes, you might or might not want that direction to rotate with your object.*